# Show that these mappings define the representations of $C_2$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am not sure how to show that these mappings:
$$1.)\quad \rho:C_2\to GL(2),~e\mapsto E_{11}+E_{22},~a\mapsto E_{12}+E_{21}\$$$

$$2.)\quad \rho:C_2\to GL(n),~e\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^nE_{ii},~a\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^nE_{i,n-i+1}$$

define the representations of $C_2$
Here's what I think:

I think I need to check group homomorphism property: verify if $\begin{aligned}\rho(ea)=\rho(e)\rho(a)\end{aligned}$ holds for every $e,a\in C_2.$ However, I am not sure I understand how to use this equation and how do I check for each $e,a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Recall that
$E_{ij}$ is [a matrix unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_unit) and $I_n$ is [the identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) of size $n$.

The only thing that needs to be checked are the two equations
$$
1)\ (E_{12}+E_{21})^2=I_2;
$$
$$
2)\ \left(\sum_{i=1}^nE_{i,n-i+1}\right)^2=I_n.
$$

And of course we must realise that
$$
E_{11}+E_{22}=I_2
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nE_{ii}=I_n.
$$

**Addendum.**

I now realise that my hint was too small. So let's look at the details.

Firstly,
$$
E_{11}+E_{22}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0\\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=I,
$$
and
$$
E_{12}+E_{21}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0\\
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=A,
$$
and $A^2=I$ (please check this).

Let $C_2$ be a cyclic group of order $2$ and $C_2=\{e,a\}$, $a^2=e$, and $e$ be an identity element of $C_2$.
Now consider a map $\rho: C_2\to GL(2)$ defined by the rules $\rho(e)=I$ and $\rho(a)=A$. Since $\rho(a^2)=\rho(e)=I$ and $\rho(a)\rho(a)=A\cdot A=I$ we have $\rho(a^2)=\rho(a)\rho(a)$. It follows that $\rho$ is a homomorphism (why?). Hence $\rho$ is a matrix representation of $C_2$.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning of $E$ and $I$ here, I am confused about this problem.

Comment: @Arbatus, I have supplemented my answer with appropriate references.

Comment: Okay, can I ask why $E_{11}+E_{22}$ and $E_{12}+E_{21}$ should be equal to $I_2$, for the first problem? How is this condition called? And where does $C_2$ come into play here?

Comment: @Arbatus, I have tried to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help